# Split string on <a> tag

Tags: javascript

I would like to split the below value:

```
var stringValue = "<a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a><a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsEN.pdf">EN</a><a href="/FR/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsFR.pdf">FR</a>";
```

As we see, there are 3 anchors hence I have tried

```
1. var result = stringValue.split("<a/>");

2. var myRegexp = new RegExp("<a/>");
   var result = stringValue.split(myRegexp);
```

What would be the best regex or way to get these 3 anchors ?

Comment: Well, first you mean `</a>`, right?

Comment: Yesy LIama - My identifier was "</a>" but you can suggest better as well

Comment: `var stringValue = '<a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a><a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsEN.pdf">EN</a><a href="/FR/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsFR.pdf">FR</a>';stringValue.split(/(?=<a)/);`

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Invalid regex too in IE

Comment: @user3674148 : https://jsfiddle.net/7v2rk3tf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a pure regex solution:

```js
var stringValue = '<a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a><a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌ionsEN.pdf">EN</a><a href="/FR/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌ionsFR.pdf">FR</a>';

var ar = stringValue.match(/<a.*?<\/a>/g)

console.log(ar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive look ahead assertion to get the splitting position

```js
var stringValue = '<a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a><a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsEN.pdf">EN</a><a href="/FR/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsFR.pdf">FR</a>';

var res = stringValue.split(/(?=<a.*?<\/a>)/);

console.log(res);
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qM2nK1/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

You are already there, just one extra step (okay, maybe 2) is required

```
var finalArray = stringValue.split("</a>").filter( function(val){
  return val.length > 0; //filter out empty results
}).map( function(val){
  return val + "</a>"; //append "</a>" to the rest of the results
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First your string contains double quotes (`"`)  you should either escape them or encapsulate it in single quotee (`'`).

```
var stringValue = '<a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a><a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsEN.pdf">EN</a><a href="/FR/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsFR.pdf">FR</a>';

var result = stringValue.split("</a>")
             .filter(function(item) { 
                  return item ? true : false; 
              })
              .map(function(item) { 
                  return item + '</a>';
              });
```